# how to add filter to tweepy stream in an flask socketio application?

Tags: stream, tweepy, flask-socketio

With my flask-socketio app, I am trying to update all connected clients when I receive a new tweet. So following is my code.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import API

access_token = "tkndfkdj"
access_token_secret = "aldkjfd;"
consumer_key = "saldkjfa;"
consumer_secret = "dkaljfad"

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,async=True)

tweet_count = 0

class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('client connected !!!')
    global myStream
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = API(auth)
    global myStream
    myStream = Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=MyListener())
    myStream.filter(track=['#python','#java'],async=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host='0.0.0.0',port=9000, debug=True)
```

In the above code I am getting error after I add the line         `myStream.filter(track=['#python','#java'],async=True)` in the `test_connect` function.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 297, in _run
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 250, in _run
    verify=self.verify)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
    cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 269, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 465, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 315 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Or any better architecture to achieve this purpose?

Below is the output of pip freeze command

```
alabaster==0.7.10
anaconda-client==1.6.9
anaconda-navigator==1.7.0
anaconda-project==0.8.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
asr-evaluation==2.0.2
astroid==1.6.1
astropy==2.0.3
attrs==17.4.0
audioread==2.1.5
Babel==2.5.3
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
bitarray==0.8.1
bkcharts==0.2
blaze==0.11.3
bleach==2.1.2
bokeh==0.12.13
boto==2.48.0
Bottleneck==1.2.1
certifi==2018.1.18
cffi==1.11.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cloudpickle==0.5.2
clyent==1.2.2
colorama==0.3.9
comtypes==1.1.4
conda==4.4.10
conda-build==3.4.1
conda-verify==2.0.0
contextlib2==0.5.5
cryptography==2.1.4
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.27.3
cytoolz==0.9.0
dask==0.16.1
datashape==0.5.4
decorator==4.2.1
distributed==1.20.2
docutils==0.14
edit-distance==1.0.1
entrypoints==0.2.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
fastcache==1.0.2
filelock==2.0.13
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-Session==0.3.1
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.0
gevent==1.2.2
glob2==0.6
greenlet==0.4.12
h5py==2.7.1
heapdict==1.0.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.6
imageio==2.2.0
imagesize==0.7.1
ipython==6.2.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.1.1
isort==4.2.15
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
jedi==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.10
joblib==0.11
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.2
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyterlab==0.31.4
jupyterlab-launcher==0.10.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
librosa==0.6.0
llvmlite==0.21.0
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.1.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
menuinst==1.4.11
mistune==0.8.3
mpmath==1.0.0
msgpack-python==0.5.1
multipledispatch==0.4.9
navigator-updater==0.1.0
nbconvert==5.3.1
nbformat==4.4.0
networkx==2.1
nltk==3.2.5
nose==1.3.7
notebook==5.4.0
numba==0.36.2
numexpr==2.6.4
numpy==1.14.0
numpydoc==0.7.0
oauthlib==2.0.7
odo==0.5.1
olefile==0.45.1
openpyxl==2.4.10
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.22.0
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.1.1
partd==0.3.8
path.py==10.5
pathlib2==2.3.0
patsy==0.5.0
pep8==1.7.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
Pillow==5.0.0
pkginfo==1.4.1
pluggy==0.6.0
ply==3.10
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
psutil==5.4.3
py==1.5.2
PyAudio==0.2.11
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.1
pyflakes==1.6.0
Pygments==2.2.0
pylint==1.8.2
pyodbc==4.0.22
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PySocks==1.6.7
pytest==3.3.2
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-engineio==2.1.0
python-socketio==1.9.0
pytz==2017.3
PyWavelets==0.5.2
pywin32==222
pywinpty==0.5
PyYAML==3.12
pyzmq==16.0.3
QtAwesome==0.4.4
qtconsole==4.3.1
QtPy==1.3.1
requests==2.18.4
requests-oauthlib==0.8.0
resampy==0.2.0
rope==0.10.7
ruamel-yaml==0.15.35
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==1.0.0
seaborn==0.8.1
searchtweets==1.7.0
Send2Trash==1.4.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.11.0
snowballstemmer==1.2.1
sortedcollections==0.5.3
sortedcontainers==1.5.9
Sphinx==1.6.6
sphinxcontrib-websupport==1.0.1
spyder==3.2.6
SQLAlchemy==1.2.1
statsmodels==0.8.0
sympy==1.1.1
tables==3.4.2
tblib==1.3.2
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.3.1
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==4.5.3
traitlets==4.3.2
tweepy==3.6.0
tweet-parser==1.13.0
TwitterSearch==1.0.2
typing==3.6.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.2.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
widgetsnbextension==3.1.0
win-inet-pton==1.0.1
win-unicode-console==0.5
wincertstore==0.2
wit==5.1.0
wrapt==1.10.11
xlrd==1.1.0
XlsxWriter==1.0.2
xlwings==0.11.5
xlwt==1.3.0
zict==0.1.3
```

Comment: Please add the output of `pip freeze` to your question.

Comment: @Miguel added output of pip freeze to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using gevent and doing networking through tweepy, it is required that you monkey patch the Python standard library so that it becomes compatible with gevent's async loop.

This is the code that you need to add to monkey patch:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

This needs to be done in your main script, and above all other imports. If you are already monkey patching, then the error is likely caused by doing the monkey patching too late, after other imports.